# Elliptic Integrals of the First Kind

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Suppose I have $$F(\phi(x), k) = x$$ where the elliptic integral of the first kind is defined to be $$F(\phi, k) = \int_{0}^{\phi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin(\theta)}} \, d\theta  $$

How could I invert this in order to make $\phi$ the subject?

Comment: Use Jacobi elliptic functions

Answer (score 1):

Maple has this (in terms of the elliptic function sn):

[image: solve]

Comment: That last function is more often denoted the *Jacobian amplitude*. Note that the Jacobian amplitude is **not** doubly periodic (it is quasiperiodic, however), and thus not elliptic, but composing it with trigonometric functions does yield elliptic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement GEdgar's answer (+1):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_as_inverses_of_elliptic_integrals) gives the definition of the Jacobi elliptic function $sn(x)$ as the inverse of the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

The article gives lots of other definitions of $sn(x)$ by means of either doubly periodic meromorphic functions or alternatively in terms of theta functions, but I believe you re going to be disappointed if you want an inverse function which is easily expressible in terms of elementary functions - sorry.